# Arraylist index calculation java

Tags: java, arraylist, continuous

I have array list that each indexes has value either 0 or 1.I want to find that continuously three indexes has the value 1.How do I find it?

Comment: Please show us your attempts thus far so we can determine where you're stuck and what needs explaining.

Comment: iterate over the list and check if the current item and the next two items are == 1. thats a way how you find it, now you have to code it.

Comment: try writing a bit of code :), then let us know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without actual code:

1. iterate thorough the array
2. count the 1s you found
3. if you found a 0 then start over the count
4. check after increasing the counter: if the counter reaches 3 then return with `true`
5. if you reached the end of the array and no more elements then return with `false`

Something like this, I hope I could help.